# Limiting distribution for proportion of MVN components exceeding fixed threshold

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems, large-deviation-theory

Let $X_i$ be the coordinates of a centered $n$-variate normal distribution satisfying
$$
\mathrm{cov}(X_i,X_j) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }\; i=j \\
a & \text{if }\; i\neq j
\end{cases},
$$
where the pairwise covariance $0<a<1$ is fixed and does not depend on $n$.
Fix $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $$Y_n := \frac{\#\{i:X_i\geq t\}}{n}$$
be the proportion of $X_i$'s exceeding the threshold $t$.
So $Y_n$ are discrete RVs taking values in $[0,1]$.

**Question:** What is the limiting distribution of $Y_n$ as $n\to\infty$?

Numerically $Y_n$ seem to converge (weakly) to a continuous distribution on $[0,1]$, and this behaviour is clearly different from the case of independent RVs governed by the CLT.

Below is the plot of the density of $Y_n$ for $a=0.1$, $n=10^4 \text{ and } 10^6$. The threshold $t$ is so that $\mathbb{E}Y_n=0.2$.

[image]

Comment: A promising direction was to consider the corresponding stationary Gaussian process $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ so that $Y_n$ become ergodic sums $$Y_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(T^ix),$$ where $f(x) = \mathbb{1}_{[t,\infty)}(x_0)$ and $T$ is the shift transformation $(Tx)_i=x_{i+1}$.

The problem is that the corresponding spectral measure $\sigma = a\delta_0 + (1-a)\text{Leb}$ is continuous (and equivalently $T$ is ergodic) only if $a=0$. I don't know how the ergodic components look like in the non-ergodic case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution by Roman Vershynin.*

We can realize $X_i$ as
$$
X_i = \sqrt{1-a}g_i + \sqrt{a}h
$$
where $g_i$, $h$ are (jointly) independent $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random variables.

Condition on $h$. This makes $X_i$ (conditionally) independent. Thus, by the strong law of large numbers, for any value of $h$, we have
$$
Y_n \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} 
\mathbb{P}\{\sqrt{1-a}g + \sqrt{a}h \geq t\mid h\}
= \mathbb{P}\Bigl\{g \geq \frac{t - \sqrt{a}h}{\sqrt{1-a}} \mid h\Bigr\}
= \Phi\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt{a}h - t}{\sqrt{1-a}}\Bigr) =: f(t, h)
$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cumulative distribution function.

Thus, for every fixed values $h$, $q$:
$$
\mathbb{P}\{Y_n \leq q\mid h\} \to
\mathbb{1}_{\{f(t, h) \leq q\}}
$$

Notice that $f(t, h) \leq q$ iff $h\leq \frac{\sqrt{1-a}\Phi^{-1}(q)+t}{\sqrt{a}}$.
Taking expectation w.r.t. $h$ on both sides, we get
$$
\mathbb{P}\{Y_n \leq q\} \to \mathbb{E}_h \mathbb{1}_{\{f(t, h) \leq q\}}
= \Phi\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{1-a}\Phi^{-1}(q)+t}{\sqrt{a}}\bigg)
$$